# Overlapping Polygon's, z-index and before/after

Tags: html, css, svg, z-index

I want to reach this result: [image]
This is what i have atm: http://mijnwebsitebestellen.be/index.php

So i am currently using SVG elements to slice of the images. You can inspect the code in your browser. I can't get the result right because of z-index issues.

Any tips or examples of any sort are appreciated.

Comment: I can provide more info if needed?

Comment: SVG doesn't have  z-index. It's painter's model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result using pure CSS.

- Use a container element for background color and image
- Use the pseudo element `::after` with a white right border to imitate the right edge
- Use some divs of the same class `.tile` to imitate the stripes with `transform: skewX(-10deg);` and let them `float: right;`

Et voilà:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(219, 41, 117, 0.6), rgba(219, 41, 117, 0.6)), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e11Va.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 26px;
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 52px solid white;
  border-top: 300px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.tile {
  width: 30px;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-left: 5px solid white;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Of course you can add content to the container. Just use another div inside the container and give it the apropriate width.

Comment: Just a little bonus question: i used your technique here http://mijnwebsitebestellen.be/index.php . Now when you hover over "event location" you can see the image is temporarily not skewed. I use jquery to animate the width of the element. Is there a quickfix for this?